# substring fails in WHERE condition of MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I break my head over the following:
I tried using `SUBSTRING`, `REGEXP` etc.
I now have a simple query to select when last four chars of filed is 2014:

```
SELECT c.`virtuemart_category_id`, cl.`category_name`, cc.`category_parent_id`, cc.`category_child_id`
FROM `#__virtuemart_categories` AS c
JOIN `#__virtuemart_categories_nl_nl` AS cl using (`virtuemart_category_id`)
JOIN `#__virtuemart_category_categories` AS cc ON cl.`virtuemart_category_id` = cc.`category_child_id`
WHERE c.published = "1" AND RIGHT(cl.`category_name`,4) = "2014"
ORDER BY c.`ordering`
```

also tried:

```
(substring(cl.`category_name`,-4) = "2014")
```

Returns zero results (probably a fault in syntax, but I can not see an error).

What I eventually want is to select when last four chars are not a number. Field contains CHAR values.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP ? What does this output: `SELECT RIGHT(category_name, 4) FROM #__virtuemart_category_categories_nl_nl`

Comment: category_name doesn't sound like a datetime field :/  Can you add a few rows of the table to see what category_name looks like?

Comment: column category_name has different values. I need to only select values which do not contain a year. Values include: januari 2014 but also Alaska. So I want to include the row containing ALASKA but not januari 2014. So 2014 is basically part of the value. It is not important that this is a year, though they all are years.

Answer (score 0):

Your question should really include sample data.  Ideally, you would put an example up on SQL Fiddle.

My best guess is that there are additional characters after the year.  Try this:

```
WHERE c.published = 1 AND cl.category_name like '%2014%'
```